# Porting Legacy code to 64 Bit in C++

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to port a legacy 32 bit code to 64 bit. In that we have a union like this:

```
union ptType
{
    int * iPtr;
    short * sPtr;
    long * lPtr;
    bool * bPtr;
    double * dPtr;
};
```

As you can guess, this union is used to store addresses of all these types.  I have read about a lot pointer size and arithmetic changing in 64 bit. But am not too sure of this behavior. This code seems to work in QA, but I am more apprehensive about production as it would enormous traffic there.

How will porting to 64 bit affect the behavior of the code?

Comment: You haven't told us the current behavior of the code, so how can we know how it'd change?

Comment: A datatype doesn't have behaviour on it's own. ptType is a datatype. I will have behaviour when it's used by other code. So what usage are you concerned about - can you post code using the union which you are concerned about?

Comment: My concern is an enum pointer is stored and later it is accessed using an int pointer. How will it behave in this particular case?  The compiler we are running has all pointers to be of same size. But I think it not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

You're right that under most 32- to 64-bit transitions, those pointers will all double in size.  The operation of this union itself is unlikely to be a problem, but you'll have to look out for places where it interacts with other code, via typecasts, hardcoded sizes, etc.

Comment: A bigger concern would be issues like endianness and word alignment, given that the original code is taking a few liberties with things.

Comment: 32- to 64-bit transition almost always means Intel, doesn't it?  In that case, neither endianness or alignment are likely to be a concern.  Maybe some structure padding - but that's not a problem for this union.

Comment: @HotLicks - What liberties is the original code taking? And how do you know?

Comment: I have checked all the code. It has a 'datatype' variable stored along with it which says which type of pointer is stored in the union. So I assume its fine. But there is one code where "it stores an enum pointer and accesses it using an int pointer". I am worried about this particular case. Can you put light on this.

Comment: @user1699086, assuming that `enum` type is equivalent to `int`, you'll be fine.  That would have been a problem in the original code, too.

Comment: Yes. Thats what I thought. But since we were using gcc 2.8.* earlier which had same size for enum and int pointers, it worded fine. Now we are moving to gcc 4.4.* on RHEL 6 64 bit. This has same size for them. But It may change isn't it?

Comment: There is not a requirement in the C standard that any two pointer types have the same size.  In practice, all pointers on a given platform are almost always the same.  There are some exceptions for some oddball Harvard architecture microcontrollers, but probably not in your case.

Comment: @CarlNorum - 32 to 64 bit transition could be from an IBM 360 or a DEC VAX to an Intel or an IBM Power.

Comment: @user93353 - The use of a union like that indicates that the programmer was apt to be "clever" with pointers and alignments.  Been programming for 40 years, so I know "clever" when I see it.  "Clever" isn't necessarily bad, but it can hold a few surprises.